# Dictionary not returning correct value

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement

Code below - followed by description of my problem;

```
ends_partial_dict = {
    'PLAIN END' : 'PE',
    'MPT' : 'MNPT',
    'PE': 'PE',}

original_description = (r'Pipe SA-106 GR. B SCH 40 PE 24" WALL smls'.upper())
item_split = original_description.split()
```

Returns: `['PIPE', 'SA-106', 'GR.', 'B', 'SCH', '40', 'PE', '24"', 'WALL', 'SMLS']`

```
def item_end_partial() :
   not_found = True
   for key in ends_partial_dict:
        if key == item_split:
            item_end_partial_1 = ends_partial_dict[key]
            return (item_end_partial_1)
            not_found = False
            break
   if not_found :
            return ("What are ENDS?")
print(item_end_partial())
```

For some reason, it is returning my "if not_found" value of "What are ENDS?" instead of the dictionary value of 'PE'.

I've tried a number of different ways to adjust the dictionary value and the function setup but nothing has seemed to work. Anyone know why this is not pulling 'PE'?

Comment: You are comparing each key to the entire list. You probably want `key in item_split` instead.

Comment: `if key == item_split`: you're directly comparing a single string to a list of strings. Do you mean `if key in item_split:`?

Comment: This: `if key == item_split:` will never be true since `key` is a string and `item_split` is a list.

Comment: You are comparing two different types: dictionary Key (strings) and item_split (list). This can't match so you `not_found = False` will not be executed.
EDIT: I should train speed typing on my keybord

Comment: btw, since you have an early `return`, the next two lines are redundant.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
Use a debugger to step through your program and observe its flow and the values in the variables you're comparing against each other.

Comment: Thanks guys! Glad it was such an easy fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have lots of redundancy in your code, plus you should be passing values into your function, not relying on global variables:

```py
ends_partial_dict = {
    'PLAIN END' : 'PE',
    'MPT' : 'MNPT',
    'PE': 'PE',}

original_description = r'Pipe SA-106 GR. B SCH 40 PE 24" WALL smls'.upper()
item_split = original_description.split()
# Returns: ['PIPE', 'SA-106', 'GR.', 'B', 'SCH', '40', 'PE', '24"', 'WALL', 'SMLS']

def item_end_partial(item_split, ends_partial_dict) :
    for key in ends_partial_dict:
        if key in item_split:
            return ends_partial_dict[key]
    return "What are ENDS?"

print(item_end_partial(item_split, ends_partial_dict))
```

Comment: Thanks quamrana, I am pretty new to coding so my initial goal is to get the framework of my app functional with a gui then go back and fine tune/learn how to make it more efficient. Good advice to build on later so thanks again for that!